# Server sent events using Html5 EventSource & Spring SseEmitter

Tags: javascript, java, html, spring, server-sent-events

I have implemented a very basic server sent http streaming in my app

Client side code

```
 var receiveRealTimePost=(function(){
 var rtUrl= '${fetchRealTimePost}';
 alert('Real time post function invoked');
 var source = new EventSource(rtUrl);  
 source.onmessage=function(event){
 document.getElementById("result").innerHTML+=event.data + "<br/>";
 };
 })();
```

Server side

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getRealTimeServerPushUserPosts")
    public SseEmitter getRealTimeServerPushUserPosts(){

        SseEmitter sseEmitter = new SseEmitter();
        try {
            sseEmitter.send("Message #1");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return sseEmitter;
    }
```

The connection is established. But on the UI why does the browser poll for the server every second. The alert is visible on the UI every second.

[image]

How does it make different from polling? 
I saw the same thing happening with the twitter streaming REST API the browser polls the server every second.

[image]